# ¿Uff y uy son intercambiables?

Tags: modismos, colombia

Me parece que "uff" y "uy" son términos bastante similares. ¿Cómo se puede elegir entre los dos?

¿Son básicamente intercambiables? ¿Se usan de la misma forma en todo el mundo hispanohablante?

Answer (score 2):

**Uf** está recogida en el Diccionario de la lengua española con una sola "f" pero **con dos acepciones**:

- [**uf**](https://dle.rae.es/uf)

> 1. interj. U. para denotar cansancio, fastidio o sofocación.)
> 2. interj. **Indica repugnancia.**

El diccionario recoge otra interjección muy parecida, pero de uso restringido a la Argentina y el Uruguay:

- [**ufa**](https://dle.rae.es/ufa?):

> 1. interj. *Arg. y Ur.* U. para expresar fastidio, fatiga o desagrado.

El DLE recoge la forma **huy**, sinónimo de **uy**:

- [**huy**](https://dle.rae.es/uy)

> V. uy.

- [**uy**](https://dle.rae.es/huy):

> Tb. huy.
> 1. interj. U. para denotar dolor físico agudo, vergüenza o asombro.

Por lo que, volviendo a la pregunta planteada, la respuesta es clara: **no son en general intercambiables** ya que tienen un significado diferente.
Si podríán serlo en casos concretos, en los que se pudiera dar tanto asombro (uy) como repugnancia (uff). Por ejemplo, supongamos que una persona se tropieza inesperadamente con un cuerpo en descomposición.

Comment: Todo lo que pusiste, lo pusé yo.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tienes un montón de interjecciones:

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjecci%C3%B3n)

Entre ellas, hay:

¡órale!: para exhortar o para manifestar asombro o aceptación. Coloquial en El Salvdor, Guatemala, Honduras y México.
**¡uf!1​ sirve para denotar cansancio, fastidio o sofocación.**
¡uh!: para denotar desilusión o desdén.
**¡uy!: expresa asombro, sorpresa por algo insólito. Según la RAE se puede escribir con hache o sin ella**

uf con una f, no dos.

Y la RAE, por uy: dice

**uy
Tb. huy.
Del lat. hui.**

1. interj. U. **para denotar dolor físico agudo, vergüenza o asombro.**

[RAE](https://dle.rae.es/huy)

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con sofocación, hartazgo o de agotamiento, pero en el único contexto en que lo he visto usado como intercambiable es cuando tiene connotación sexual o para expresar deseo anticipado por comida, es decir, de sofocación, hartazo o de agotamiento pero por algo que vas a consumir o disfrutar en exceso, anticipándose a lo que se viene.

Ufff=Uyyy, que rico está, que rica estás mami, si que está buena, está que arde(=she's hot, atractiva, países del caribe)(en algunos países es irrespetuoso)